# Python Azure function not working after deployment from VSCode

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk

I am new to Azure and tried some python scripting based on our business logic to interact with other Azure services. I have followed the documentation and successfully achieved the task in VS Code, but later after deploying my function to Azure it is not working as expected and throwing some **internal server** errors.

Below are the files which are configured by following Microsoft Azure Documentation:

- local.settings.json
- function.json
- function --> init.py

Looking forward for any help on this, thanks much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Azure function is working fine locally it should work after the deployment as well. In few cases after deploying our function we will get internal server errors when we run our code.

Below are two ways we can get rid of it.

1. Add Application Settings ( Add all the variables from local.settings.json under Configurations ) and Save.
   [image]
2. If our Azure function is interacting with any of Azure Service or Blob storage we need to add the API link in CORS, or you can try adding “*”.
   [image]

The above two issues will help us in Internal Server errors.

Refer to this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal) for adding Application Settings

Comment: thanks, as you said I am accessing storage, added the link in CORS, solved my problem.

Comment: Glad, it helped you